# XGBoost installation via Anaconda 1.5.1 fails on OS X

Tags: python, anaconda

I have GCC installed via Homebrew using `brew install gcc --without-multilib`.  When I tried to use `pip install xgboost` in Anaconda 1.5.1 on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 and Conda 4.1.11 running Python 3.5.2, I get the following output and error:

```
Collecting xgboost
  Using cached xgboost-0.6a2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    rm -f -rf build build_plugin lib bin *~ */*~ */*/*~ */*/*/*~ */*.o */*/*.o */*/*/*.o xgboost
    clang-omp++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/learner.o src/learner.cc >build/learner.d
    /bin/sh: clang-omp++: command not found
    clang-omp++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/logging.o src/logging.cc >build/logging.d
    make: *** [build/learner.o] Error 127
    make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    /bin/sh: clang-omp++: command not found
    make: *** [build/logging.o] Error 127
    -----------------------------
    Building multi-thread xgboost failed
    Start to build single-thread xgboost
    rm -f -rf build build_plugin lib bin *~ */*~ */*/*~ */*/*/*~ */*.o */*/*.o */*/*/*.o xgboost
    clang-omp++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/learner.o src/learner.cc >build/learner.d
    /bin/sh: clang-omp++: command not found
    make: *** [build/learner.o] Error 127
    make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    clang-omp++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/logging.o src/logging.cc >build/logging.d
    /bin/sh: clang-omp++: command not found
    make: *** [build/logging.o] Error 127
    Successfully build single-thread xgboost
    If you want multi-threaded version
    See additional instructions in doc/build.md
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/94/yw1tx2t95lb31nlww2nwpk114lvh7b/T/pip-build-k_1ed1r6/xgboost/setup.py", line 29, in <module>
        LIB_PATH = libpath['find_lib_path']()
      File "/private/var/folders/94/yw1tx2t95lb31nlww2nwpk114lvh7b/T/pip-build-k_1ed1r6/xgboost/xgboost/libpath.py", line 45, in find_lib_path
        'List of candidates:\n' + ('\n'.join(dll_path)))
    XGBoostLibraryNotFound: Cannot find XGBoost Libarary in the candicate path, did you install compilers and run build.sh in root path?
    List of candidates:
    /private/var/folders/94/yw1tx2t95lb31nlww2nwpk114lvh7b/T/pip-build-k_1ed1r6/xgboost/xgboost/libxgboost.so
    /private/var/folders/94/yw1tx2t95lb31nlww2nwpk114lvh7b/T/pip-build-k_1ed1r6/xgboost/xgboost/../../lib/libxgboost.so
    /private/var/folders/94/yw1tx2t95lb31nlww2nwpk114lvh7b/T/pip-build-k_1ed1r6/xgboost/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/94/yw1tx2t95lb31nlww2nwpk114lvh7b/T/pip-build-k_1ed1r6/xgboost/
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by following the [Python Package Installation instructions.](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/build.md)  I now have the package without a pip installation.