# install xgboost in virtual env with error code 1

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, xgboost

I try to install xgboost in virtual environment on Mac Sierra, but got the error code 1. Full information as below, please help. Many thanks.

```
Collecting xgboost


     Using cached xgboost-0.6a2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    rm -f -rf build build_plugin lib bin *~ */*~ */*/*~ */*/*/*~ */*.o */*/*.o */*/*/*.o xgboost
    clang-omp++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/learner.o src/learner.cc >build/learner.d
    /bin/sh: clang-omp++: command not found
    make: *** [build/learner.o] Error 127
    make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    clang-omp++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/logging.o src/logging.cc >build/logging.d
    /bin/sh: clang-omp++: command not found
    make: *** [build/logging.o] Error 127
    -----------------------------
    Building multi-thread xgboost failed
    Start to build single-thread xgboost
    rm -f -rf build build_plugin lib bin *~ */*~ */*/*~ */*/*/*~ */*.o */*/*.o */*/*/*.o xgboost
    clang-omp++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/learner.o src/learner.cc >build/learner.d
    /bin/sh: clang-omp++: command not found
    make: *** [build/learner.o] Error 127
    make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    clang-omp++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/logging.o src/logging.cc >build/logging.d
    /bin/sh: clang-omp++: command not found
    make: *** [build/logging.o] Error 127
    Successfully build single-thread xgboost
    If you want multi-threaded version
    See additional instructions in doc/build.md
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/kd/chcp2c9j5vz93c4fzft0dmnm0000gn/T/pip-build-vfgVmn/xgboost/setup.py", line 29, in <module>
        LIB_PATH = libpath['find_lib_path']()
      File "/private/var/folders/kd/chcp2c9j5vz93c4fzft0dmnm0000gn/T/pip-build-vfgVmn/xgboost/xgboost/libpath.py", line 45, in find_lib_path
        'List of candidates:\n' + ('\n'.join(dll_path)))
    __builtin__.XGBoostLibraryNotFound: Cannot find XGBoost Libarary in the candicate path, did you install compilers and run build.sh in root path?
    List of candidates:
    /private/var/folders/kd/chcp2c9j5vz93c4fzft0dmnm0000gn/T/pip-build-vfgVmn/xgboost/xgboost/libxgboost.so
    /private/var/folders/kd/chcp2c9j5vz93c4fzft0dmnm0000gn/T/pip-build-vfgVmn/xgboost/xgboost/../../lib/libxgboost.so
    /private/var/folders/kd/chcp2c9j5vz93c4fzft0dmnm0000gn/T/pip-build-vfgVmn/xgboost/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so

----------------------------------------
```

Command `"python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/kd/chcp2c9j5vz93c4fzft0dmnm0000gn/T/pip-build-vfgVmn/xgboost/`

I try to install xgboost in virtual environment on Mac Sierra, but got the error code 1. Full information as below, please help.

Comment: `clang-omp++: command not found` tells you the compiler is not installed.

Comment: The error code seems to be 127 in each instance.  The numeric error code does not really reveal the nature of the error unless you know from which program the error code came, anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006804/xgboost-installation-via-anaconda-1-5-1-fails-on-os-x/39007799

Comment: Thanks for the clue. When I tried to follow the link as given I got the following error message when trying to make -j4                                           In file included from src/c_api/./c_api_error.h:9:0,
                 from src/c_api/c_api_error.cc:6:
dmlc-core/include/dmlc/base.h:153:23: fatal error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/types.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.